# Serving video files from Tornado

Tags: http, http-headers, video-streaming, html5-video, tornado

I have a few hundred video files on my server.
Since I'm not a big business, I find it difficult to transcode and maintain copies in the storage available to me. My setup involves nginx and Tornado.

To solve this problem, I decided to try and transcode on the fly and serve these *temporary files* on-demand.

Before I attempted to create a `subprocess` to try and convert files for me, I decided to try and serve a static video file via Tornado.

```
class MediaHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def serve(self, media, max_bufsize=1*1024*1024):

        bytes_read = 0
        file_length = None
        remaining = None

        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'video/mp4')
        with open(media.name, 'rb') as f:
            while 1:
                # While transcoding, file size will be changing
                # So compute every time
                file_length = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size  # Get current length
                remaining = file_length - bytes_read    # Compute remaining bytes

                # Hopefully we're producing faster than we're consuming...
                if remaining == 0:
                    break

                buffer_size = max_bufsize if max_bufsize < remaining else remaining
                bytes = f.read(buffer_size)
                assert len(bytes) == buffer_size
                bytes_read += buffer_size

                self.write(bytes)
                self.flush()


    def get(self):
        log('Media Request: %s' % (self.request.uri))
        #XXX: Currently this is hard-coded in some sense..fix it
        media_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path, self.request.uri[1:]))  #Strip leading '/'
        log('media_path: %s' % (media_path))
        try:
            media = avprobe(media_path)
        except SubprocessException, e:
            raise e

        if media.video_codec not in valid_video_codecs or \
                media.audio_codec not in valid_audio_codecs:
            # Transcode and serve
            pass
        else:
            self.serve(media)
        self.finish()
```

I noticed that when I tried to serve the file from Tornado, Firefox would not load the video at all.
Upon checking, my response headers were as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 00:04:50 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: TornadoServer/4.2
```

Nginx seems to generate the following headers when I ask it to serve the same file:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2015 23:57:06 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 65796881
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 21:47:56 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Etag: "5526f38c-3ebfb11"
Content-Range: bytes 0-65796880/65796881
```

It seems Firefox doesn't like the data that I'm sending it.
It spits out the following on the console:

```
Media resource http://xxxx:8000/video_test/media/test.mp4 could not be decoded.
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

Could someone point out what I'm doing incorrectly and how to serve static media from Tornado (without using `StaticFileHandler`..since I don't think I can use this for my ultimate purpose).

Also, is there a better way to achieve on-the-fly transcoding+streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don't like to download the whole file for an embedded video; they want to be able to issue HTTP `Range` requests to download partial chunks (to support seeking, etc). Some browsers are very strict about this and refuse to load a video at all if it doesn't have the correct `Content-Range` header. Unfortunately this makes it difficult to serve video when the file size is not known in advance.

If the files are small enough that you can transcode the whole thing to a temporary file before serving it, then you can just do that and then serve `Content-Range` in the same way that `StaticFileHandler` does. If not, then I think you may need to use a more complex protocol such as [HLS or MPEG-DASH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video) to make this work for all browsers.

Comment: I think this is what might be happening. I think in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#page-12, it says I can use `Content-Range` even when the length is unknown. I will try this out with the unknown `Content-Range`